# Yesterday into YYYYMMDD format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date-formatting

I'm looking to add in a condition to my already badly performing SQL code. I want to add in a filter where the date =  yesterday (data type as `INT`).

For example

```
Select * 
From table
Where Date = 20190930
```

How do I do this using `GETDATE() - 1`?

Comment: why are you using `int` for date value ? If you are able, change to `date` data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your query.

Firstly, you need to cast your `int` date to a `varchar` before covenrting to `datetime`, to avoid an arithmetic flow error during conversion.

Secondly, you need to cast `getdate() - 1` as `date` to truncate time to match your date field.

```
select *
from table
where cast((cast(date as varchar(8))as datetime) = cast(getdate() - 1 as date)
```

**or**

```
select *
from table
where cast((cast(date as varchar(8)) as date) = cast(dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0) as date)
```

Comment: my query use to run from 30+ minutes to now 50 seconds!!! Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: update,  with explanation. thanks dale for the comment.

Comment: Converting the column to a string prevents the use of indexes.  This is not the best solution.

Comment: It may seem simple, but because of localization issues converting back and forth between dates and strings is a surprisingly expensive operation... something to avoid whenever possible. ("string" date literals in SQL code as treated as date values by the query optimizer from the beginning)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Date datatype is int, what if hundreds of applications are using it?

Answer (score 3):

We need to be very clear about what data type you're using.

If you have a simple `date` value (no time component as part of the data type), things are pretty easy:

```
Select * 
from table
where Date = DATEADD(day, -1, cast(current_timestamp as date))
```

If you have a `DateTime` or `DateTime2` value, it's important to understand that all `DateTime` values have a time component that goes all the way down to milliseconds. This is true even when you expect the time component to always be at or near midnight. That can make straight equality comparisons difficult. Instead, you almost always need check within a specific **range**:

```
Select * 
from table
where Date >= DATEADD(day, -1, cast(current_timestamp as date))
    AND Date < cast(current_timestamp as date)
```

Comment: This is definitely the better solution and should be accepted.

Comment: date as what op mentioned is int not datetime. there are many situations, that sometimes we need to make things done asap, like quick fix in real world of software development.

Comment: Even in those situations, piping through varchar is still pretty much never the most expedient option, and it opens you up bugs from all kinds of edge cases around unexpected culture and collation uses.

Comment: what if hundreds of applications are using this field, are we going to update everything just to satisfy best practice of creating date columns? reason why we ask help from stackoverflow because we are desperate of getting the fastest workaround and fix.

Comment: @EdBangga Old now, but in that case you should _**still avoid converting to varchar!**_ Convert the `current_timestamp` to the `int` format used by your column, not the other way around, so that indexes are still valid and you don't create bugs when another application or server with different string formatting submits the query. varchar for dates is _pure evil_. And that's just in the moment. Long term, you should consider this a weakness to address. The schema you have is **broken**.